# Visual Studio 2017: error not letting me push to a remote repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to push my local repo on to my remote repo on Github. I've tried recreating my local repo. I've tried different instructions for publishing local repos so I don't think there's anything wrong with that process. I'm using the URL that Visual Studio generates. https://github.com/CalebADB/Static-Motion.git I'm running windows 10 and visual studio 2017.

I'm not trying to use git bash or learn any new software so if you have any simple solution that'd be great but I'm still open to trying different solutions

The error read:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://github.com/CalebADB/Static-Motion.git
```

Thank you

Comment: Recommend better justifying the C++ tag. It seems tangential at best.

Comment: This looks like a permissions problem; check that the cached username & password are correct.

Comment: What version of VS 2017 are you using? There's a rather long discussion about this [on GitHub](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949); seems that a lot of people had success recently (aka, end of February) by updating VS to >= 15.5.7